# xhr.onreadystatechange never gets called

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a pretty simple scenario:

I have a *span* element like this:

```
<span  id="spin">
     <img class="diamond-size cursor" src="images/gem.png">
 <span>
```

I have registered a click event to trigger *startSpinState()* function like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    var spinButton = document.getElementById("spin");
    spinButton.addEventListener("click", () => startSpinState());
});
```

Inside that function there is a call of the method called *apiCallOwner()* that creates a promise and resolves it when the API call is finished. *startSpinState* looks like this:

```
function startSpinState() {
    apiCallOwner('/bet', 'POST', betsData).then(response => {
           // do something
    }
}
```

And finally, *apiCallOwner()* looks like this:

```
function apiCallOwner(path, method, data) {
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('In apicall');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = API_URL_OWNER + path;
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Session-Id", window.sessionIdValue);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log('Response from owner API');
            console.log(json);
            resolve(json);
        }
        // else {
        //  reject('Error!');
        // }
    };
    if (method === 'POST') {
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    } else {
        xhr.send();
    }
});
return promise;
```

}

It all seems fine to me, however when I click the button onreadystatechange never gets executed. I tried to debug and it seems that the execution just stops. I also tried to inspect traffic with wireshark and I see that no request has been made

**EDIT:** I just went to the network tab in Chrome and saw that my requests are pending for ever. For each request I have 2 requests: 1 containing the body. That seems like normal situation where one request is OPTIONS request and the other one is POST, but they never complete. And also there is no *Request Method* specified. This is how it looks like for the request that I suspect is the OPTIONS request: Request URL:

```
http://*server-ip*/bet
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,session-id
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:8000
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: My first suggestion is, don't use XMLHTTPRequest unless you have to support Internet Explorer (and is there really a reason to anymore?). Use the Fetch API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch Considering you're using promises, I don't think that'll be an issue for you.

Comment: There's also Fetch polyfills for old browsers. https://github.com/github/fetch TL;DR don't use XMLHTTPRequest. :)